# how to free an allocated array in a function in c

Tags: c, function, memory-management, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

If we were to use `malloc()` in `main()`, we could `free()` that dynamic memory allocation in `main()`.

However, if we use `malloc()` in a different function
and  we use that function in `main()`, where should we call `free()` to release the memory allocated in that function?

I.e., in the following source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * memory_allocate_function(int);

int main(void) {
    int n=5; //length of array, 5 for example.
    int *my_array;
    my_array = memory_allocate_function(n);
    return 0;
}

int * memory_allocate_function(int n) {
    int i;
    int *array;
    array=(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL) {
        printf("can not allocate memory.");
        return NULL;
    }
    // I think i can't use "free(array);" in here.
    // Because I need that array in main().
    return array;
}
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Who said you have to call `free` in `main` if you call `malloc` in `main`?

Comment: Have you actually tried to put a free there and compile / run ?

Comment: Because, yes, you can and should use free right where that doubting comment in your code is.

Comment: i fixed question, now i need that array in `main()`

Comment: Your new comment is correct. Now you free it in main. BTW, it is rather discorteous to significantly change the meaning of your code after people have posted good answers.

Comment: @MadPhysicist my mentor said that :S
and yes i did compile / run it .

Comment: @MadPhysicist i will consider your comments about changing the meaning of code and question meaning. thanks.

Comment: No worries. Learn as you go. I'm glad you found the help you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after you are done working with it - `free` the dynamically allocated memory. But design wise - *you can call the `free` in other function also to manage it properly*. It really depends. There is no hard rule for that.

For example here you should return that pointer to allocated memory and then after using it in `main` you can free it in `main()`.

So the structure would be something like

```
int* memory_allocate_function(int n)
{
    int i;
    int *array;
    array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not allocate memory.");
        exit(0);
    }
     return array;
}
```

Then in `main()`

```
int main(void)
{
    int n=5;    //length of array, 5 for example.
    int *arr = memory_allocate_function(n);
    // work with arr
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

But yes *name the function properly* - if you are going to use the name `memory_allocate_function` function then do that only - not any other major logic should be there. This helps create a good readable code.

---

Note one thing - here when you called the function and then you exited the function the only local variable that contains address of it, it's storage duration ended and you can never then access the memory you allocated. This is a case of memory leak. If you are determined that you won't return the  pointer to memory from the function - then work with it (in the same function or different) and then free it (Before the scope of the function ends - notice not mentioning about where you would free it, you can do it in the same function and other function also).

<sup>I can't help mentioning few things:- 1) Dont cast the return value of `malloc`. 2) Check the return value of `malloc` - in case it is `NULL` you would like to handle it separately. 3) The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`</sup>

Comment: so, what if i write `free(memory_allocate_function(n));` to before `return 0;` of end of the **int main(void)** ? this is the last question of mine about that.

Comment: @Sillyon:Yes you can do that provided the returntypeof the other function is int* and the pointer to the allocated memory is returned from the function. Now you will do all the work with the memory in that function only.

Comment: @coderedoc ok, although it does not serve the purpose; i will do all the work with the memory in that function only, right. thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Sillyon.: Well  in memory_allocate_function you can pass the pointer to other function which will take it and work with it. But in `main` where you are supposedly calling the `free`...it can't be used.

Answer (score 4):

Memory should be freed when it's no longer needed.

Since the array would no longer be accessible after `memory_allocate_function` exits (since the `array` isn't returned or otherwise made accessible to the outside), it should be freed before `memory_allocate_function` exits.

```
void memory_allocate_function(int n){
    int i;
    int *array;
    array = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.");
        exit(1);
    }

    // ... use the array ...

    free(array);
}
```

Comment: what if array would be accessible with `return array;` end of the function?

Comment: Memory should be freed when it's no longer needed. It doesn't have to be in the same function that allocated it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to `malloc` memory in one function and `free` in another, you have to somehow carefully pass the pointer to that `malloc`ed memory from the point of `malloc` to the point where you want to `free` it.

This is your responsibility to preserve the pointer value and hand it from one function to another until it reaches the point of `free`. If you lose that value along the way, you'll have a memory leak. A memory leak is what you have now, since you are not passing that local `array` pointer anywhere.

There's no "one true way" to do it, since it depends on your specific intent. For example, you can return that pointer from `memory_allocate_function`, receive it `main` and eventually `free` it there

```
int *memory_allocate_function(int);

int main()
{
  int n = 5;
  int *arr = memory_allocate_function(n);
  ...
  free(arr);
  return 0;
}

int *memory_allocate_function(int n)
{
  int *array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
  ...
  return array;
}
```